# Top xml element "Student" won't color

Tags: css, xml

I know this sounds like a problem that would be common but I searched all over stack overflow and could not find anything. The problem I am right now having is the top xml element "Students" won't get a background color from the css. I have the xml nested properly and everything and I have spelled the XML element correctly in my css file. I have tried an xml validator and the document appears to be well formed. So what could possibly be wrong?

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylexml.css"?>
<Registration>
    <Student>
        <Id>0001234567</Id>
        <University>Indiana University Purdue University Indianapolis</University>
        <Education>Undergraduate</Education>
        <Category>Technology Undergraduate</Category>
        <Degree>Computer Tech BS</Degree>
    </Student>
    <Semester>
        <Season>Spring Semester</Season>
        <Year>2004-2005</Year>
        <Bterm>Senior</Bterm>
        <Eterm>Senior</Eterm>
    </Semester>     
    <Class id="0">
        <Course>CIT 412</Course>
        <Number>12981</Number>
        <Section>0100</Section>
        <Description>XML-BASED WEB APPLICATIONS</Description>
        <Component>Lecture</Component>
        <Grading>Graded</Grading>
        <Grade> </Grade>
        <Units>3.00</Units>
        <Status>Enrolled</Status>
        <!--New instance of schedule only created if time or location differs on weekdays-->
        <Schedule id="0">
            <Start>1:00PM</Start>
            <End>2:15PM</End>
            <Weekday>Mon,Wed</Weekday> 
            <Location>SL SL223</Location>
        </Schedule>
        <Instructor>Fernandez, Eugenia</Instructor>
        </Class>
    <Class id="1">
        <Course>CIT 479</Course>
        <Number>12988</Number>
        <Section>0100</Section>
        <Description>DATABASE IMPLEMENTATN &amp; ADMIN</Description>
        <Component>Lecture</Component>
        <Grading>Graded</Grading>
        <Grade> </Grade>
        <Units>3.00</Units>
        <Status>Enrolled</Status>
        <Schedule id="0">
            <Start>7:15PM</Start>
            <End>8:30PM</End>
            <Weekday>Mon</Weekday> 
            <Location>SL SL223</Location>
        </Schedule>
        <Schedule id="1">
            <Start>7:15PM</Start>
            <End>8:30PM</End>
            <Weekday>Wed</Weekday> 
            <Location>SL SL216</Location>
        </Schedule>
        <Instructor> </Instructor>
    </Class>
    <Class id="2">
        <Course>MATH M-119</Course>
        <Number>15304</Number>
        <Section>0400</Section>
        <Description>BRIEF SURVEY OF CALCULUS 1</Description>
        <Component>Lecture</Component>
        <Grading>Graded</Grading>
        <Grade> </Grade>
        <Units>3.00</Units>
        <Status>Enrolled</Status>
        <Schedule id="0">
            <Start>5:45PM</Start>
            <End>7:15PM</End>
            <Weekday>Mon,Wed</Weekday> 
            <Location>LE 104</Location>
        </Schedule>
        <Instructor>Tam,Richard Yiu-Hang</Instructor>
    </Class>
</Registration>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

Registration
{
    font-family:"MS Serif", "New York", serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-style:normal;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
Student
{
    background-color:red;
}
Id,University,Education,Category,Degree
{
    display:block;
    //background-color:blue;

}
Semester
{
    background-color:yellow;
    border-bottom-style:ridge;

}
Class 
{
    margin-top:20px;
    border-style:solid;
    display:block;
    background-color:cyan;  
}
Course
{
   font-weight:bolder;
}
Description, Component
{
    display:block;
}
Schedule
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Are the other CSS styles to the other tags being applied ok?

Comment: Yeah the other CSS tags work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `Student` element as block element in rendering:

```
Student { display: block }
```

By default, it is an inline element, since in XML, the initial value (`inline` for `display`) is used when no style sheet assigns value to a property and the property is not inherited (`display` isn’t). So `Student` will be a poor lonesome inline element, with all its children occupying their blocks, leaving nothing to have the background for. You can see this if you add just plain text inside the `Student` element: it will take the red background.

An element does *not* become a block element in rendering just because its children are block elements.

Note that your code has the malformed line `//background-color:blue;`. It will be ignored, as per CSS error handling rules, but it’s still an error; you can’t use JavaScript comments in CSS; instead, a comment in CSS is of the form `/* comment text */`.